# Installing dependencies for Python program

Tags: python, installation

I have created a Python-based GUI application which has certain dependencies such as the "request" and "psycopg2" modules among others.

I want to create a setup script that will install all such dependencies when run, so that a user can run the GUI application without having any missing package errors.

I did try looking up the distutils module, but am not able to fully understand its usage.

Answer (score 3):

if you did

```
$ pip install SomeLib
```

to satisfy a requirement for developing your own library, you should have a setup script something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=['SomeLib']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify all dependent packages in the 'install_requires' option within your setup.py - that's it.

If this is not sufficient or good enough (for whatever reason): look into zc.buildout giving your more options installing and configuring external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [impstall](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/impstall) package, a project I created to meet these same needs.  It's as simple as:

```
import impstall
impstall.now('csv')
impstall.now('wx', pipName='wxPython')
```

Comment: Please do disclose your association with this package; this is your own project. See [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I started it.